# Unable to pick webelement attribute value from Excel file and use it in the driver.getElement()

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

> Unable to pick webelement attribute value from Excel file use it in the driver.getElement

Please read through my comments added within the code. When using variable and hardcoding the value in it works fine when using it in the method when the same is tried to get it from Excel it shows `exception as Null value`.

//Base class is StackOver-- I am reading excel file here

```
package functionlibrary;`enter code here`

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StackOver {
    String g_Amount_Pay;
    public static void createdriver(){
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.Chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    }

    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

    static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.properties");
        }
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("BaseClass");

    public void GetExcelData(int eRow) {
         try {
              // Specify the path of file
              File src=new File("C:\\Users\\joins\\eclipse-workspace\\WC_WebsiteProject\\MyFile.xlsx");

               // load file
               FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

               // Load workbook
               XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

               // Load sheet- Here we are loading first sheet only
               XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

              int noOfColumns = sh1.getRow(eRow).getLastCellNum(); 

              g_Amount_Pay=sh1.getRow(eRow).getCell(25).getStringCellValue();
              System.out.println("ID value picked from excel----"+g_Amount_Pay);
              wb.close();
              } //end of try

            catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              } 
     }
}

package functionlibrary;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;


  public class OneOff_S extends StackOver {
        String l_Amount_Pay="amountToPay-0005485-01"; 
        public final By amountPay1=By.id(l_Amount_Pay);
        public final By amountPay2=By.id(g_Amount_Pay); 

        public void enter() {

            driver.get("C:\\Users\\joins\\Desktop\\Oneoff.html");
            driver.findElement(amountPay1).sendKeys("100"); //working
            System.out.println("Run time value---"+driver.findElement(amountPay1).getAttribute("id"));
            driver.findElement(amountPay2).sendKeys("100"); 
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(amountPay2).getAttribute("id"));

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            OneOff_S ob1=new OneOff_S();
            ob1.GetExcelData(1);
            ob1.enter();
        }

  }


/* error console
Starting ChromeDriver 
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 25, 2017 7:53:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements with a null id attribute.
    at org.openqa.selenium.By.id(By.java:53)
    at functionlibrary.OneOff_S.<init>(OneOff_S.java:9)
    at functionlibrary.OneOff_S.main(OneOff_S.java:23)
*/
```

/* console executed
Starting ChromeDriver 
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 25, 2017 7:56:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
ID value picked from excel----amountToPay-0005485-01
Run time value---amountToPay-0005485-01
*/

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: Are you sure this code is expect: System.out.println(g_Ammount_Pay);//working,  it shoud be g_Ammount_Pay2 ? you can add a if statement like if(g_Ammount_Pay2 == null) {// print some log},  and you should tell us what error it report?

Comment: where is `g_Ammount_Pay2` defined? In the BaseClass?

Comment: can you print and show value of "g_Ammount_Pay2"?

Comment: Hi Kushal, these are the values, ID value picked from excel----amountToPay-0005485-01  ; Run time value---amountToPay-0005485-01